# As Sal, why would I convince the Admiralty to lift the quarantine?

Tags: griftlands

In Sal's story, at the end of the 3rd day you need to go to the docks to retrieve a package. However, the Admiralty has quarantined the ship that brought the package. You can cut a side deal with the Admiralty clerk on hand to get the package, or you can convince them to lift the quarantine; lifting the quarantine gives the clerk +30 resolve for going against orders.

Given that both options result in you getting the package, why would you try to convince the clerk to end the quarantine (one of the hardest negotations in the game)? What extra benefit does it give?